# I am trying to use python's objectpath to pick specific values out of a multi-level json/dictionary, but can't get to my desired target format

Tags: python, json, dictionary, objectpath

Imagine I hit an API and it returns a multi-level json blob. I want to then pull specific values out of that blob and then upload it to a database, so I need to flatten it.

Basically I want to move from something like this:

```
d1 = {'results': [
        {'a': 1, 'b': 10},
        {'a': 2, 'b': 20},
        {'a': 3, 'b': 30, 'c': {'d': 100, 'e': 1000}},
        {'a': 4, 'c': {'d': 200, 'e': 2000}}
    ]
}
```

To something like this (ideally with the labels adjusted to represent the original hierarchy):

```
d2 = [
    {'a': 1, 'b': 10},
    {'a': 2, 'b': 20},
    {'a': 3, 'b': 30, 'c.d': 100},
    {'a': 4, 'c.d': 200}
]
```

I feel like jsonpath or objectpaths should be able to do this, but I haven't been able to get it to work. I could traverse this example fairly easy, but I have a bunch of these to do so something more "declarative" would be much preferable.

I must be missing something on how these path things work. Here's my attempt:

```
from objectpath import Tree

# starting here...
d1 = {'results': [
        {'a': 1, 'b': 10},
        {'a': 2, 'b': 20},
        {'a': 3, 'b': 30, 'c': {'d': 100, 'e': 1000}},
        {'a': 4, 'c': {'d': 200, 'e': 2000}}
    ]
}

# trying to get here...
# d2 = [
#     {'a': 1, 'b': 10},
#     {'a': 2, 'b': 20},
#     {'a': 3, 'b': 30, 'c.d': 100},
#     {'a': 4, 'c.d': 200}
# ]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = Tree(d1)
    print([x for x in t.execute('$.results.a')])  # works to get value of a
    print([x for x in t.execute('$.results.(a,b)')])  # creates dictionary of a & b -- cool
    print([x for x in t.execute('$.results.(a,b,c)')])  # adds all of c's sub document, makes sense
    print([x for x in t.execute('$.results.(a,b,c.d)')])  # nothing changed?
    print([x for x in t.execute('$.results.*')])  # selects everything, sure
    print([x for x in t.execute('$.results.*["a"]')])  # just "a" value again, makes sense
    print([x for x in t.execute('$.results.*["a" or "b"]')])  # apparently this means HAS "A" or "B" -- weird?
    print([x for x in t.execute('$.results..(a,b,d)')])  # almost works but puts d in it's own dictionary?!
    print([x for x in t.execute('{"a": $.results.a, "b": $.results.b, "c.d":  $.results.c.d}')])  # what I would expect, but not even close
```

## results

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[{'b': 10, 'a': 1}, {'b': 20, 'a': 2}, {'b': 30, 'a': 3}, {'a': 4}]
[{'b': 10, 'a': 1}, {'b': 20, 'a': 2}, {'b': 30, 'c': {'d': 100, 'e': 1000}, 'a': 3}, {'c': {'d': 200, 'e': 2000}, 'a': 4}]
[{'b': 10, 'a': 1}, {'b': 20, 'a': 2}, {'b': 30, 'c': {'d': 100, 'e': 1000}, 'a': 3}, {'c': {'d': 200, 'e': 2000}, 'a': 4}]
[{'b': 10, 'a': 1}, {'b': 20, 'a': 2}, {'b': 30, 'c': {'d': 100, 'e': 1000}, 'a': 3}, {'c': {'d': 200, 'e': 2000}, 'a': 4}]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[{'b': 10, 'a': 1}, {'b': 20, 'a': 2}, {'b': 30, 'c': {'d': 100, 'e': 1000}, 'a': 3}, {'c': {'d': 200, 'e': 2000}, 'a': 4}]
[{'b': 10, 'a': 1}, {'b': 20, 'a': 2}, {'b': 30, 'a': 3}, {'d': 100}, {'a': 4}, {'d': 200}]
['b', 'a', 'c.d']
```

I seem to be so close, but maybe i'm doing this completely the wrong way?
would something like marshmallow work better? That just seemed like overkill as I'd have to define a class hierarchy.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple recursion:

```
from pprint import pprint


def flat_dict(d: dict):
    o = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if type(v) is dict:
            o.update({
                k + '.' + key: value
                for key, value in flat_dict(v).items()
            })
        else:
            o[k] = v
    return o


def main():
    d = {
        'result': [
            {'a': 1, 'b': 10},
            {'a': 2, 'b': 20},
            {'a': 3, 'b': 30, 'c': {'d': 100, 'e': 1000}},
            {'a': 4, 'c': {'d': 200, 'e': 2000}}
        ]
    }

    res = [
        flat_dict(e)
        for e in d['result']
    ]
    pprint(res)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

result:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 10},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 20},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 30, 'c.d': 100, 'c.e': 1000},
 {'a': 4, 'c.d': 200, 'c.e': 2000}]
```